# Add array of strings to a Labels within a cell subview

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview, uiview, uilabel

I have a cell which has a custom UIView subclass as one of its contentView subviews. The subclass will be used as a Tag list.

Within the cell creation method I complete the following call to the subclass:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[searchResultCell.categoriesView createLabelsForArray:newCats];
```

Which calls the following method:

```
-(void)createLabelsForArray:(NSArray *)labelArray {
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    for (NSString *labelTextString in labelArray) {
        NSLog(@"label string : %@",labelTextString);

        NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12], NSFontAttributeName,
                                             nil];

        CGRect frame = [labelTextString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(128, 15)
                                                options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine
                                             attributes:attributesDictionary
                                                context:nil];
        CGSize size = frame.size;
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label.text = labelTextString;
            NSLog(@"label frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(label.frame));
        [self addSubview:label];
    }

    NSLog(@"self frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
```

This is what is happening:
[image]

Whilst this is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Hi @StuartM, what do you see when you log the individual label frames? Why are you putting them all on point {0,0}?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing each newly created label with a frame origin of `(0,0)`. This means that each label you add to your categoriesView will be added on top of each other. Every time you add a new label you need to increment the subsequent label's `x` position by the `width` of the current label.

Second, since `-createLabelsForArray:` is being called within `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you will end up adding new, duplicate labels whenever this method is called if `searchResultsCell.categoriesView` isn't a new view each time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. You might want to check if the labels have already been added before adding them again, or at the very least delete the old labels before adding the new ones.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. What would be the best way to store the width in the for loop and reuse, as for the first object I need 0,0 then I need to store for any others? Is there an easy way to clean the holder view in `cellForRow...` each time?